# Monitorar tempo de um usuário na página com PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Como eu poderia registrar no banco de dados a saída do usuário?
Eu tenho esse código PHP que pega a entrada, andei lendo que poderia ser feito com JS, mas eu não tenho tanto conhecimento.

```
    <?php   include 'menu.php';


session_start();
$user = $_SESSION['usuariox'];
//echo "<br>";
$loja = $_SESSION['nroempresa'];
//echo "<br>";
$nvl = $_SESSION['nivel'];
//echo "<br>";
$data_1 = $_SESSION['data_1'];
//echo "<br>";
$data_2 = $_SESSION['data_2'];

error_reporting(0);
//echo "<br>";


if($user == TRUE) {
  date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
  $data = date('d/m/y'); 
  $hora = date('H:i');
  include ("conexao_local.php");

  $sql = "INSERT INTO web.dash_log (data,usuario,loja,hora) VALUES ('$data','$user','$loja','$hora','$saida')";
  $stmt = oci_parse($conexao, $sql);
  oci_execute($stmt); }

  ?>
```

Quando ele entra no site já registra a entrada no banco, abaixo tem todo conteúdo do site, eu queria que quando ele fechasse registrasse, ou então, que atualize o banco a cada 30 segundos com a data de saída..algo do tipo.

Consegui fazer ele pegar a hora com esse Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
new Date().toLocaleTimeString(); // 15:46:33


// mostra datatime correndo
window.onload = function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
    }, 50000);
};
</script>
```

Como eu atribuo o valor da hora a $saida? to com bastante dificuldade na lógica

Comment: Dê uma lida nessa resposta: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40877307/5988245. Considere ler as outras também, mas essa é a principal.

Comment: Cara, pior que não entendi o que ele faz

Comment: Consegui listar a hora a cada tempo, mas agora é como eu jogo isso pra registra no update do banco..ali no javascript? Preciso criar um update.php? mas como eu jogo essa hora para lá?

Comment: Pois é cara, a empresa quer saber se os líderes estão usando os relatórios disponibilizados, eu acho que vai ficar uma M... isso ai, sabe uma outra forma?

Comment: Ja faço isso, eles logan eu registro a data e a hora..Mas dizem que eles podem acessar e fecha o site sem olhar.. ¬¬

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91909/discussion-between-lipespry-and-ricardo-goncalves).

Comment: você saiu do chat

Comment: Entrei lá de novo e vc não respondeu, até que vc "caiu do chat". Não posso ficar todo esse tempo esperando. kk

Comment: Consegui, bem bão :D